# What db permissions are needed for pgAgent user?

Tags: postgresql

I have successfully set up pgAgent daemon (running on the same server as Postgres 9.3). I would like to restrict permissions on pgAgent. Created 'pgagent' login role, and granted it (via group role) all permissions on postgres.pgagent schema:

```
CREATE ROLE pgagent LOGIN
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
CREATE ROLE scheduler
NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
GRANT scheduler TO pgagent;
grant all on schema pgagent to scheduler;
grant all on all tables in schema pgagent to scheduler;
grant all on all functions in schema pgagent to scheduler;
grant connect on database postgres to scheduler;
```

However pgAgent refuses to execute any jobs, and just sits there idly. No error messages in logs. If I start pgagent as 'postgres' user it runs fine. Or, if I 'grant postgres to scheduler' it also runs fine.

What permissions am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Had this same issue!

Looking in the postgres log it appeared pgagent was failing to invoke one of the sequences in order to add entries into the job log.  Once I did the below (in postgres 9.3) and restarted my pgagents, all worked well:

```
GRANT ALL ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA pgagent TO pgagent_user;
GRANT ALL ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA pgagent TO pgagent_user;
```